# How can I create a loop to add all the volumes of these boxes?

Tags: java, loops

I'm undergoing the first year of my degree and can't seem to solve this problem, I need to return the total volume of all the boxes using a loop. The hint I was given is

```
double totalVolume=0;
for(Box bx:boxes)
{
    totalVolume=totalVolume+'the volume of box'
}
System.out.println("Total volume="+totalVolume);
```

however on the totalVolume=totalVolume+'the volume of box line i'm getting an error and can't figure anything out. Sorry if this is a really simple fix.

**Main Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Box a=new Box(40,20,20);
    Box b=new Box(40,30,20);
    Box c=new Box(40,20,30);
    Box d=new Box(50,30,30);
    Box e=new Box(60,20,10);
    Box f=new Box(80,10,10);

    ArrayList<Box>boxes=new ArrayList<>();
    boxes.add(a);
    boxes.add(b);
    boxes.add(c);
    boxes.add(d);
    boxes.add(e);
    boxes.add(f);

    //Box x=boxes.get(1);
    //Box y=boxes.get(0);
    Box v=boxes.get(0);
    Box w=boxes.get(1);
    Box x=boxes.get(2);
    Box y=boxes.get(3);
    Box z=boxes.get(4);
    Box u=boxes.get(5);
    u.print();
    v.print();
    w.print();
    x.print();
    y.print();
    z.print();

    for(Box bx:boxes)
    {
        bx.print();
    }

    double totalVolume=0;
    for(Box bx:boxes)
    {
        totalVolume=totalVolume+'the volume of box'
    }
    System.out.println("Total volume="+totalVolume);
}

}
```

**Box Class**

```
class Box
{
  int width;
  int height;
  int depth;

  public Box(int width, int height, int depth)
  {
      this.width=width;
      this.height=height;
      this.depth=depth;
  }

  public void print()
  {
      System.out.println("Width="+width);
      System.out.println("Height="+height);
      System.out.println("Depth="+depth);
      System.out.println("Volume="+volume());
  }

  public int volume()
  {
      return (width*height*depth);
  }


}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "giving an error" is not sufficient. What error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `Box` class has a `volume` method. If you have a box *instance* or *object*, then you can invoke the `volume` method on it as

```
box.volume();
```

Hence, your code needs to be

```
for(Box bx : boxes) {
    totalVolume = totalVolume + bx.volume();
}
```